# Не удается применить какие-либо свойства для классов

Tags: css

Не удается применить какие-либо свойства для классов. Для всех других элементов (`body`, `div`) все применяется и норм работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: box2 надо точку поставить вперёд, .box2

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в браузер, открой страницу, нажми f12, перейди во вкладку память (для хрома) и вообще браузер воспринимает линк или нет, если статус 200 у файла css, тогда смотри код, если вообще не грузил, то смотри как ты написал линк